# how to merge a pull request in two branches?

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-pull

I have two branches `develop` and `test`.
`test` is behind `develop` which was created few weeks back.

I have created a pull request for `test` and my team member merged it.
Now I want to push the same change to `develop` branch.
I tried cherry-pick but it didn't work.

Is there anyway, I can pull the same pull request to `develop` branch?

Comment: Do you want to use the github UI or are you OK with command line instructions? You get a small step-by-step tutorial how to merge a PR manually in open PRs.

Comment: thanks. I want a commandline steps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `pull` is nothing more than a `fetch` followed by a `merge`.

Hard to say without having more info on your commit tree, but you should be able to `git checkout` the develop branch, `git merge` with `test` (or whatever commit you're trying to `merge` with), and then `git push` your local `develop` branch to the remote repo's `develop` branch.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand, your team member merged `test` in `master` when he accepted the pull request.

To now merge it in `develop` you could simply do, in your local repo

```
git checkout develop
git merge test
git push origin develop
```